# Error 404 while executing GetRequest() for a listing directory on FTP with proxy

Tags: c#, proxy, ftp, http-status-code-404, getresponse

I can tell you in advance that my URL is ok. Recently we've moved our server applications and the urrent systems have a nice proxy.

So, i think that the proxy is being the problem, but no idea in how to solve, the most strange thing is, with Filezilla i can log into FTPServer, but with my .Net code is impossible, i tried to change to Binary, to Passive, manually specifying proxy... but no success. It always crashes on GetResponse(). Other interesting thimg is, when i not use the `wilcard` (that is, `*.csv`), the response is an HTML with the information with the file list.

My Code:

```
FtpWebRequest listRequest = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(
            ftpDir == null ? Constants.FTPServer + (wildcard == null ? "" : "/" + wildcard) : Constants.MasternautFTPServer + "/" + ftpDir
            + (wildcard == null ? "" : "/" + wildcard)
            );
listRequest.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.ListDirectory;
listRequest.UseBinary = true;
listRequest.UsePassive = true;
listRequest.Credentials = Credentials;
listRequest.Proxy = Proxy;
FtpWebResponse listResponse = (FtpWebResponse)listRequest.GetResponse();

Stream listResponseStream = listResponse.GetResponseStream();
StreamReader listreader = new StreamReader(listResponseStream, Encoding.UTF7);
string listOfFilesStr = listreader.ReadToEnd();
ret = new List<string>(listOfFilesStr.Split(new[] { "\r\n" },StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries));
ret.Remove(".");
ret.Remove("..");
ret.Remove(".ftpquota");
listreader.Close();
listResponse.Close();
```

Where `Proxy` is obtained by the method `WebRequest.GetSystemWebProxy();`

So, now i'm investigating in how to solve this... Could annyone help???

Comment: does the proxy actually support ftp?

Comment: Actually yes, in fact i solved the issue by simply assign as FTP address the proxy address, the user as [ftpaddressftpuser] and the ftp password. Now all works like a charm!!! The problem was the huge infrastucture in my company, information flow within persons is not very good... ;-) Thanks. I will publish a response with the solution...